# Magento Observer is not firing, why?

Tags: magento-1.8, model, event-observer

I have truble with observer, don't know how to solve it!

Here is part of the config.xml and Observer.php files

**Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_mysql4>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <mymodule>
                        <table>mymodule</table>
                    </mymodule>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_mysql4>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                <observers>
                    <mycompany_mymodule_order_complete>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>mymoduleCompleteOrder</method>
                    </mycompany_mymodule_order_complete>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
       </events>
 </global>
```

**Mycompany/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer 
{
    protected $_config;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_config = Mage::getModel('mymodule/config');
    }

    public function mymoduleCompleteOrder($observer)
    {...
      ....
    }
```

Comment: Is the rest of your module working? Do you have the module declaration file in `app/etc/modules` ?

Comment: yes, working fine, only observer do not work!

Comment: IN the config.xml you declared your method used for the event `mymoduleCompleteOrder` and in the observer the method name is `mymodulesCompleteOrder`. There is an additional `s` in the observer class. Could that be it?

Comment: it my fault in write here! both same!

Comment: try `Mage::getModel('mymodule/observer');` if this works try `$observer-> mymoduleCompleteOrder('test');` if this works too, you need to check, whether the event is fired!?

Comment: welcome Fabian, where should I test theme? in the observer.php?

Comment: tested first method and result is `object(Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer)#134 (1) { ["_config":protected]=> NULL }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what exactly problem you have, but I see one problem in your code.

In your observer you have `_construct()` method.

It is not the php constructor (php constructor has two underscores).

Also your observer does not extend `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which runs _construct()` method during object initialization.

So as a result `_construct()` will not be executed and `protected $_config;` will always be null.

If you use `$this->_config` in `mymoduleCompleteOrder()`, it can generate error, and your code is not executed correctly.

Comment: Yes true, I removed `protected $_config;` and `_construct()` from my code and then worked fine